# Do eliptical chainrings give you an advantage

Tags: road-bike

Has anyone tried oval chainrings? Are they worth the time and money? Any brands worth considering? I'm trying to gain any advantage I can get

Comment: The jury is out, studies are inconclusive. Any benefit is likely highly individualistic (e.g., psychological).

Comment: The best upgrade is likely yourself - add muscle, lose weight.  If the bike is limiting you then you're fitter than most people.

Comment: I used to have ellipticals, on my old bike, and they seemed to make riding marginally easier.  (I noticed the difference when I swapped them in for the original round rings.)  But I don't miss them on my current bike, and I suspect they create problems with indexed shifters.

Comment: I used to have ellipticals, on my old bike, and they seemed to make riding marginally harder. (I noticed the difference once I got a new bike with round rings.) I don't miss them at all, they had a weird feel to them.

Comment: Looks like this is "primarily opinion-based" to some people. Care to explain why?

Answer (score 0):

No, they won´t give you any advantage. It didn´t show a benefit in comparison with normal chainrings since the transference in watts doesn´t change. If you want to get any advantage you should look for loosing weight as much as possible on the bike and having better performance parts will surely help but in the end, the only way to get advantage is training. Unless you do 28 hours a week, you should focus in your training first.